# Undefined variable Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel

I have cool models and controllers. The function does not output variables. I registered the path in the routes, but still gives an error. Writes that the `footers` variable was not found.

web

```
Route::get('/app', 'SystemController@footerAll')->name('footers');
```

controller

```
 public function footerAll(){
    return view('layouts.app', ['footers' => System::all()]);             
 }
```

layouts/app.blade.php

```
    @forelse ($footers as $footer)
                    <div>
                        <h1>{{$footer->marketing}}</h1>
                    </div>
                 @empty
                 <h2 class="text-center">Epmty</h2>
    @endforelse
```

If I put only a slash `Route::get('/', 'SystemController@footerAll')->name('footers');`, then the error passes and the information displays, but here all the other content on the page disappears immediatelyю

conflict with this route

```
 Route::get('/', 'BlogController@articlesAll', function () {
        return view('blog.home');
    });
```

web.php

```
    Route::get('/blog/category/{slug?}', 'BlogController@category')->name('category');
  Route::get('/blog/article/{slug?}', 'BlogController@article')->name('article');
 Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth']], function(){

  Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController', ['as'=>'admin']);
  Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController', ['as'=>'admin']);
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'user_managment', 'namespace' => 'UserManagment'], function() {
  Route::resource('/user', 'UserController', ['as' =>'admin.user_managment']);
  });
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('admin.index');
});
});
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@articlesAll', function () {
    return view('blog.home');
});

Route::get('/app', 'SystemController@footerAll')->name('footers');
```

Route::post('/comment/store', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.add');

```
Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@getUser')->name('users');
```

Comment: I think you have to `@include` one of your views in the otherone. Otherwise you'll only one of them

Comment: what happens if you removed the `/` before `app`? as in `Route::get('app', 'SystemController@footerAll')->name('footers');`

Comment: @user3532758 get me error footer not found

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ How can i do this? I need to get this variable somehow

Comment: Can you share the content of your route file? Or, can you post a screenshot of the error. Do you have another route that's linking to `app`?

Comment: there is a route on the `home` in question it is published and in this file the home  `app` connects `@extends('layouts.app')`

Comment: @user3532758 since I have an app connected to home, I get two routes and its conflict

Comment: Mind sharing the content of your web.php file?

Comment: @user3532758 i added web.php in the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207499/discussion-between-user3532758-and-nikita-kurilovic).